# Ruby unit test add a test suite to an already existing test suite

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I have a test suite with me. I want to add another test class with a set of tests in the test suite. Since this is a class with test cases, I do not know how to add it to the test suite.

`testsuite` - existing test suite.
FactorTest.rb - test class with test methods (class name is `FactorTest`)

I tried

```
testsuite<<FactorTest
```

and then

```
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(testuite)
```

but it fails:

```
/ruby/1.8/test/unit/testsuite.rb:54:in `size': undefined method `size' for
FactorTest:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: i m looking for the above option as i m trying to conditionally include a testsuite in an already existing test suite

Answer (score 0):

From the docs at  http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit.html

```
 require 'test/unit/testsuite'
 require 'tc_myfirsttests'
 require 'tc_moretestsbyme'
 require 'ts_anothersetoftests'

 class TS_MyTests
   def self.suite
     suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite.new
     suite << TC_MyFirstTests.suite
     suite << TC_MoreTestsByMe.suite
     suite << TS_AnotherSetOfTests.suite
     return suite
   end
 end
 Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(TS_MyTests)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just re-open the FactorTest class and add more methods to it?

```
# In test file 1
class FactorTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_1
    assert true
  end
end

# In test file 2

class FactorTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_2
    assert true
  end
end
```